# X1 Carbon Battery drains on suspend

Tags: systemd, power-management, manjaro, suspend, battery

I typically suspend my laptop between sessions to save battery without powering off fully.

I have a new 2019 Lenovo X1 Carbon, running Manjaro Linux 5.2.0-1 and when I suspend my machine with

```
systemctl suspend
```

The screen shuts off at it all seems to be suspended, but the battery barely lasts 24 hours in this state. I used to have a 2013 Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro and when I suspended the machine using the same method, the battery would easily last several weeks.

How can I suspend my X1 Carbon laptop in such a way that the battery will last for over a week?

Comment: Maybe the suspending is not done at all but rather only the screen blacked. Try pinging the device or run a cron job echoing date to a file every 5 minutes to see if the PC is still active. Side note: since Manjaro is an Arch derivate and Arch is known for its very good wiki, you might want to search there, too: [Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issues. Try checking which suspend state your machine is entering. On mine I get:

```
$ sudo journalctl | grep "PM: suspend" | tail
Jul 27 14:00:32 x1 kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Jul 28 09:52:51 x1 kernel: PM: suspend exit
```

From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/states.txt it looks like "s2idle" is a pseudo-sleep state that will consume considerable more power than actual sleep states such as "standby" or "deep". I'm going to try changing it so when I close the lid it enters "standby" and see if that help.

Comment: very interesting, I see `s2idle` also, how might I go about configuring suspend for the deeper more effective suspend-to-RAM options? Any luck?

Comment: have you advanced on this since then?